# Python exercise Vigenère code

Tags: python, vigenere

I have a question about this code below:

```
ALPHA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def main():
 encrypt_code = codeer('NOBODY EXPECTS THE SPANISH INQUISITION!', 'CIRCUS')
 print("{}".format(encrypt_code))
 print("{}".format(decrypt('CIRCUS', encrypt_code)))

def codeer(tekst, sleutel):
 pairs = zip(tekst, cycle(sleutel))
 code = ""

 for pair in pairs:
    total = reduce(lambda x, y: ALPHA.index(x) + ALPHA.index(y), pair)
    code += ALPHA[total % 26]

 return code;
```

This code will crash, because the message contains a whitespace and a ! sign.

> total = reduce(lambda x, y: ALPHA.index(x) + ALPHA.index(y), pair)
>   ValueError: substring not found

Can anybody help me with my problem

Following is an example of the expected output:

```
codeer('NOBODY EXPECTS THE SPANISH INQUISITION!', 'CIRCUS')
'PWSQXQ MORYUVA VBW AGCHAUP KHIWQJKNAQV!'

decodeer('PWSQXQ MORYUVA VBW AGCHAUP KHIWQJKNAQV!', 'CIRCUS')
'NOBODY EXPECTS THE SPANISH INQUISITION!'
```

Comment: use [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) to avoid throwing an error? (although that will give you wrong results I guess)

Comment: You should explain what the expected output and behavior is - e.g.: what is supposed to happen with the whitespace and exclamation mark characters?

Comment: Hello there,I am currently using find to see in the character exists in the alphabet, however, I get the following exception:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that all you need to do is to code/decode only when the character in question is an uppercase letter. See below for an example of what I have in mind.

```
def codeer(tekst, sleutel):
    pairs = zip(tekst, cycle(sleutel))
    code = ""

    for pair in pairs:
        if pair[0].isupper():
            total = reduce(lambda x, y: ALPHA.index(x) + ALPHA.index(y), pair)
            code += ALPHA[total % 26]
        else:
            code += pair[1]
    return code
```

You may observe its execution [here](http://ideone.com/Mbi1nf). It seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: @Michael They are the same. The only difference is the leading and trailing single-quotes, which you can concatenate, if they are really important. Am I missing something else that is different?

Comment: @Michael the code you provided in your question does not contain the function decodeer, which is why the ideone link I included in my response does not have that call to decodeer in main() function. If you can add the code for decodeer to your question I can modify my answer to include a modification to decodeer, which is pretty similar to codeer.